# How to deserialize from .proto schema into runtime type using protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a case where I fetch a .proto file at runtime and then would like to parse and create a deserializer for it at runtime? Is this possible with protobuf-net?

I have tried to parse the proto file into a FileDescriptorSet and that works fine, but I cannot find a way to get to a TypeModel to get a deserializer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ability to get a full serializer from a schema is not currently implemented; in theory the necessary APIs exist, including the ability to populate a dummy/opaque object (from `Extensible`) that allows runtime query of unexpected fields (where all the fields would be unexpected in this case), but nothing more involved. To date, I simply haven't seen likely use-cases for this, so the area hasn't been explored in depth.